# Difference in overflow behavior for same program in C# and VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I ran a program in .Net 3.5 using C# which works fine

```
try
{
    int i = 2147483647;

    Console.WriteLine((i * 100 / i).ToString());

    Console.ReadLine();
}
catch (Exception)
{                
    throw;
}
```

When I run this program in C#, I don't get an exception (it outputs "0").  But when I run this program in VB.Net it results in `"Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow"` exception

```
Try
    Dim i As Integer = 2147483647

    Console.WriteLine((i * 100 / i).ToString())

    Console.ReadLine()
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw
End Try
```

Why the different behavior between these two languages?

Comment: Maybe because VB.NET does overflow checking by default whereas C# doesn't?

Comment: BTW, *nothing* about BODMAS/PEMDAS implies that the answer should be 0 - this is a result of how C# is performing the overflow.  In this case, (i * 100) = -100.

Comment: @MichaelBray: My interpretation was that this was a question about `(i * 100) / i` vs. `i * (100 / i)`...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I agree - I've edited the question to remove the references to BODMAS/PEMDAS.   Nikhil, I also removed the images you included, because they didn't really provide any additional value that couldn't be simply described, and they just made the question hard to read.

Comment: `(i * 100) / i` is just `100`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps looking at the IL will clarify...   Simplifying your code a bit:

C#:

```
int i = 2147483647;
int v = (i * 100 / i);
```

generates the following IL:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4      FF FF FF 7F 
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // i
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // i
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.s    64 
IL_000A:  mul         
IL_000B:  ldloc.0     // i
IL_000C:  div         
IL_000D:  stloc.1     // v
```

while the VB version:

```
Dim i As Integer = 2147483647
Dim v As Integer
v = i * 100 / i
```

generates this IL, slightly different:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4      FF FF FF 7F 
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // i
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // i
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.s    64 
IL_000A:  mul.ovf     
IL_000B:  conv.r8     
IL_000C:  ldloc.0     // i
IL_000D:  conv.r8     
IL_000E:  div         
IL_000F:  call        System.Math.Round
IL_0014:  conv.ovf.i4 
IL_0015:  stloc.1     // v
```

As you can see, VB is calling `mul.ovf`, which is "multiply, and check for overflow", and C# is calling `mul` which does not check for overflow.

Perhaps it doesn't answer your question as to *why* C# does it one way and VB the other, but at least it answers why it is happening.  :)

**Edit:** see [the answer by aquinas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17499606/50356) to get the "why".

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your program to this:

```
try {
    checked {
        int i = 2147483647;
        Console.WriteLine((i * 100 / i).ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
catch (Exception) {
    throw;
}
```

C# doesn't automatically perform arithmetic checking by default. However, if you go to project properties...Build Tab..Advanced..."[X] Check For Arithmetic overflow/underflow" then you will get the same behavior as VB.NET by default.

Comment: Yup - I confirmed that the IL output (see my response) does indeed switch to using `mul.ovf` instead of `mul` inside the `checked` block.

Answer (score 0):

The output is different because the VB code you posted is *not* equivalent to the C# code.
The correct conversion is:

```
Console.WriteLine((i * 100 \ i).ToString())
```

Note that C# performs integer (truncating) division on integers, while in VB you have to use the integer division operator '\' to do the same integer division.

(update: even when using the correctly converted integer division operator, I also get the same exception in my test, so obviously it's not just about the operator).